# Spliting a table column in 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis

I have a this column :

```
t.geography "longlat", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"st_point", :geographic=>true}
```

So basically im trying to work with postgis methods,and i need to get this column splited in 2, one with X coordinate data and the other one with y coordinate data.

Edit:
My final task is to use this query :

```
Proba.where("ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(x,y),ST_MakePoint(48.33300000000003, 33.0)) <= 500")
```

To comparare all longlat points to one im manualy putting to se if they are near 500 meters. But i only can make it work with 2 columns x,y not with only one, so im trying to make my longlat column into 2 and separate x and y coordinates.

Edit: photo of select postgis version:
[image]

Comment: You can use the `ST_X` and `ST_Y` functions to extract the latitude and longitude from a point. Beyond that you question is very unclear - what is it that you're actually looking to  do with the data? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/getting-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis

Comment: @max im trying to use this query : **Proba.where("ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(x,y),ST_MakePoint(48.33300000000003, 33.0)) <= 500")** so i need to make my model that has only 1 column longlat with x,y coordinates saved into 2 columns to use that query

Comment: Can you please edit you question to make it clearer instead?

Comment: @max edited, hope its more clear, if anything just ask in comments and i will edit

Comment: Do you really need to extract the lat and lng? The method is documented as `float ST_DistanceSphere(geometry geomlonlatA, geometry geomlonlatB)` so you should just be able to use `Proba.where("ST_DistanceSphere(lonlat, ST_MakePoint(48.33300000000003, 33.0)) <= 500")`. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html

Comment: @max i still get error object doesn support inspect

Comment: Thats not an error. Thats just bad methodology. You have to remember that ActiveRecord::Relations are lazy loading so when you just run `Proba.where(...)` Rails will just return the relation for chaining - which is an object that can't be inspected. Use `.load` to actually perform the query. Or better yet write a class method/scope in your model and write an actual unit test to cover it.

Comment: @max the error i get using .load : (says function st_distance not existing)
**PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  no existe la función st_distancesphere(geography, geometry) (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: ...ast_locations".* FROM "forecast_locations" WHERE (ST_Distanc...** Forecast_location = Proba

Comment: Have you ensured that PostGIS is properly installed and that you have enabled the extension? Thats really an issue with your setup and not the query itself.

Comment: @max ty, i will look it up.

Comment: @max i have gem Rgeo and active adapter postigs, configured database.yml and added a migration to enable postigs to my database. Im rlly lost on what more can i do.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what to do here either but I would start by removing rails from the equation and just testing the db setup. Try using `rails db` to launch `psql` with your database connection. Then try running `SELECT ST_X(longlat) FROM my_table;` to see if PostGIS works at all.

Comment: @max what i was lacking is in psql console do `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` i will try to fix and see if its working

Comment: Could the issue have been that you created the migration to enable postgis but didn't run it?

Comment: @max i did run the migration and worked, its strange because using the query that i posted of Proba.where... with 2 columns works in ruby console, so i should have postgis installed but cant use CREATE extension postgis in psql console.

Comment: Hmm, could it be a PostGIS version issue? What does `SELECT PostGIS_Version();` tell you?

Comment: @max added a foto of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that as follows:

```
sql = "*, ST_X(my_table.longlat) as x, ST_Y(my_table.longlat) as y"
MyTable.select(sql)
```

not tested.

====

After your edit, instead of trying to break your field up I think you can use it directly:

```
Proba.where("ST_DistanceSphere(longlat::geometry,ST_MakePoint(48.33300000000003, 33.0)) <= 500")
```

again not tested.

Comment: Not working it gets object doesn suport inspection

Comment: your second query also gets me error, it just says `ST_DistanceSphere(geography,geometric ) dont exist.`

Comment: I've edited again.  Does this work?

Comment: Your query works but not for me, i did found a solution and it was using ST_Distance and passing both column and point given to geometry and doing 0.0500. Im not sure why but doing that works so far.